# Drupal 7: Views giving 500 error - stdClass::can_expose is undefined?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have a view that I have created that seems to crash and cause 500 server errors as soon as I use conditional filters with it.

The error that my server logs are giving me is:
*mod_fcgid:stderr: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::can_expose() in /sites/all/modules/contrib/views/views.module on line 1971*

So I did a grep for the can_expose function and see it fine in /sites/all/modules/contrib/views/includes/handlers.inc

I'm more convinced that its something that I might be doing wrong in my setup of the view - but I can't be sure (I'm a noob). This only seems to appear on this view that uses conditionals (and I have tried changing them numerous times to different things, seeing if that will change).

If I don't use conditional filters though - the view works fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, I recreated the view and it works fine. My thought is that something in the original view got corrupt somehow.

Workaround is in place, however - if anyone else has seen this issue, I would love to understand why this error happens